# How to do lambda integrations for API Gateways defined with AWS CDK SpecRestApi and swagger.yml/openapi

Tags: aws-lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway, openapi, aws-cdk

I am trying to auto-generate the integrations for the swagger.yml generated API Gateway by adding the *x-amazon-apigateway-integration* and write them back into the swagger.yml

```js
export class RestApiLambdaStack extends cdk.Stack { 
    // ...
    
    const swaggerYaml = yaml.parse(fs.readFileSync('src/swagger.yml').toString());
    
    const fn = new nodeLambda.NodejsFunction(...);

    for (const _path in swaggerYaml.paths) {
      for (const _method in swaggerYaml.paths[_path]) {  
      swaggerYaml.paths[path][method]['x-amazon-apigateway-integration'] = {
        uri: `arn:${cdk.Aws.PARTITION}:apigateway:${cdk.Aws.REGION}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${fn.functionArn}/invocations`,
        passthroughBehavior: 'when_no_match',
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        type: 'aws_proxy',
      }
    }
    
    fs.writeFileSync('src/swagger.generated.yml', yaml.stringify(swaggerYaml));
    
    new apigw.SpecRestApi(this, 'RestApi', {
        apiDefinition: apigw.ApiDefinition.fromAsset('src/swagger.generated.yml'),
        restApiName: 'restApi',
    });
}
```

but the result had these CDK tokens than render the definition invalid:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
  uri: arn:${Token[AWS.Partition.11]}:apigateway:${Token[AWS.Region.12]}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${Token[TOKEN.306]}/invocations
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not write the swagger.yml back to a swagger.generated.yml but to use "apigw.ApiDefinition.fromInline"

```js
export class RestApiLambdaStack extends cdk.Stack { 
    // ...

    const swaggerYaml = yaml.parse(fs.readFileSync('src/swagger.yml').toString());
    // ... adding integrations and validators
    // ... extracting permissions and entries (using the "tags" section)
    new apigw.SpecRestApi(this, 'RestApi', {
        apiDefinition: apigw.ApiDefinition.fromInline(swaggerYaml),
        restApiName: 'restApi',
    });
}
```

Then the inline swagger-yaml gets rerendered after the cdk-synth stage and the tokens replaced by their actual values.